# Rotating UIImageView and then Scaling

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm running into some difficulty when rotating and then scaling an image later on. I can successfully move and rotate the UIImageView using this code:

```
myImage.center = CGPointMake(240 - (myImage.center.x - 240), myImage.center.y);
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(240 * M_PI / 180);
```

But in another part of the code, I have the image scale larger:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.03,1.03);
myImage.transform=transform;
```

The problem is that when the image scales larger, the rotation goes back to the original.

Any ideas on how I can keep the rotation when I scale the UIImageView larger?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time you're setting the transform you are overwriting the previous value.  To fix this, change:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.03,1.03);
myImage.transform=transform;
```

to:

```
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myImage.transform, 1.03, 1.03);
```

This will modify the existing transform instead of making a new one.